# How to remove a MenuItem's vertical line between the icon column and the text

Tags: wpf

I almost have my menu item visual style the way I want it, but I cannot figure out how to hide the verticle line that used to seperate what used to be the icon column and the text column.

I am aware and have seen many other questions and answers that are trying to remove the icon COLUMN but other similar questions and answers I have found here either dont remove this line just the icon column and end up with the same result, or set the menu items background to cover it up (which I would like to avoid).

You can just barely make it out here running between the "s" and the "t" in my Test Menu Item:

[image]

My style and template thus far are as you would probibly expect it to look:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background" Color="#0A000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border" Color="#21000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="#FF999999"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Separator" Color="#00000000"/>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuContentSubmenuItemTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="0"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Background}" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="0" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="100" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuContentTopLevelHeaderTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <!--<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>-->
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuContentTopLevelItemTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuContentSubmenuHeaderTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="0"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{DynamicResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <!--<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>-->
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuContentSubmenuItemTemplateKey}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuContentTopLevelHeaderTemplateKey}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuContentTopLevelItemTemplateKey}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource MenuContentSubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: The provided code will not run: A couple of places you are referencing to  `TargetName="OpaqueRect"`. If you remove those  `<Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>` your code will run, and the seperator will not be seen. I guess what you see is a cache from previous builds. Clean up your project and build again then you will get the exceptions

Comment: @NawedNabiZada No effect and no errors

Comment: Then you didn't provide that part. And here it doesn't show the vertical separator.

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Didn't provide what part? And that section is only for the scroller anyway. Keep in mind that your systems color pallet could be set in a way that the line is not visible for you. If you got it to work mind sharing your code as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely in that you apply your style not to all MenuItems. For example, suppose you have:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Top item"
              Background="White">
        <MenuItem  Header="Sub Menu Item"
                   Background="White"
                   Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle1}" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

With such layout you will observe problem you describe with "Sub Menu Item". That is because it is placed inside Popup defined by template of parent item, and parent item has default template.

If you change it so that parent item also has your style:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="Top item"
              Background="White"
              Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle1}">
        <MenuItem  Header="Sub Menu Item"
                   Background="White"
                   Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle1}" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Problem disappears.

Comment: Is that because the line is a part of the parent container and not the individual items themselves, because I was kinda hoping for a way to disable it on an item by item basis.

Comment: Yes, if you have hierarchical menu, all child items are inside parent MenuItem container, and this line belongs to it.